# 502 Bad Gateway - Nginx

Tags: apache, nginx

I am receiving:

```
14201#0: *16 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to
upstream, client: 22.222.222.222, server: myserver.com, request: "GET 
/favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://70.88.100.212:7081/favicon.ico", 
host: "myserver.com", referrer: "https://myserver.com/"
```

From a sub domain of my `server`.  Now I've looked and know its not an issue of `fpm` because this happened when I was installing `gitlab` in a separate subdomain `git.myserver.com`.  My `plesk controller` said their was a `configuration issue` and suggested to run a `configure script` which than broke my sub domain.

Here is the thing - `git.myserver.com` is still accessible, it actually just broke the `myserver.com` instead.  I am not to sure what is going on what I have looked through my `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf` and everything seems correct.

The layout of that file is:

`include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/server.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/vhosts/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/forwarding/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/plesk.conf.d/webmail.conf;`

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

`70.88.100.212` is the primary server - I have multiple `domains` pointed there and `webspaces` built.  Those are still accessible fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if your port 7081 is listening on ip 70.88.100.212.

Try this command :

netstat -ntlpu

In your Nginx conf it should be:

location / {
        proxy_pass http://70.88.100.212:7081/;

Comment: Hey Ash thanks for the response - the problem here is everything is listening off of `7080 `- so changing  7080 to 7081   will create a bad gateway for the rest of everything